# How can I query fields of a one to many related object?

Tags: python, django

So if I have model Run and ExceutedTestResults

```
class Run(TimeStampedModel):
   RUN_TYPE_CHOICES = (
       (MANUAL_RUN, 'Manual'),
       (AUTOMATED_RUN, 'Automated'),
    )
    run_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RUN_TYPE_CHOICES)

class ExecutedTestResult(Duration):
    """Lists the results of every test case executed."""
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='run_results')
    RESULT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
       ('P', 'Passed'),
       ('F', 'Failed'),
       ('N', 'No Run'),
       ('B', 'Blocked'),
    )
    result = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RESULT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I want to create a queryset method in `class RunQuerySet(QuerySet):` which would return a queryset of runs that are all passed/no run within a single run

I'm not sure how to do this on a one to many relationship. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can query through the related model in `filter` to get your desired result - Runs, with run results of passed/no run like so.

`Run.objects.filter(run_results__result__in=['P', 'N'])`

```
class RunQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def passed_or_no_run(self): 
        return self.filter(run_results__result__in=['P', 'N'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [`as_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) method to link a custom `QuerySet` to your model:

```
class RunQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def passed_or_no_run(self): 
        return self.filter(run_results__result__in=['P', 'N'])

class Run(TimeStampedModel):
   RUN_TYPE_CHOICES = (
       (MANUAL_RUN, 'Manual'),
       (AUTOMATED_RUN, 'Automated'),
    )
    run_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RUN_TYPE_CHOICES)

    objects = RunQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Given an `QuerySet` instance of the `Run` model, you can execute `passed_or_no_run` like this:

```
runs = Run.objects.all()
runs.passed_or_no_run()
```

Now, instead of *all* run instances, you only get the instances where the `run_type` value is either `P` or `N`

Comment: Does that give me runs that exclusively have passed/no run, or does it give me runs that may have at least one test that has passed results and no runs?